# ¿Por qué no me funciona esta conversión de entero a cadena en Java?

Tags: java, array, string, matriz, conversión-de-tipos

¡Hola! Mi objetivo es mostrar el vector, y que cada vez que aparezca un número 3, ese valor sea reemplazado por el carácter "E". En el código comenté la forma que encontré para solucionar mi problema, pero es una forma tramposa, ya que no uso una conversión. ¿Por qué no me transforma el elemento del vector cuando es igual a 3, en una letra "E"?

```
package Segundopaquete;

public class Cambio {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int espacio;
    espacio = 0;
    int[] contador;
    contador = new int[27];
    for (int i = 0; i < 27; i++) { // Crear vector
        int num = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
        contador[i] = (num);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 27; i++) { // Mostrar vector
        espacio = espacio + 1;
        if (contador[i] == 3) {
            String caracter;
            // caracter = "E";
            caracter = String.valueOf(contador[i]);
            System.out.print("[" + caracter + "]");
        } else {
            System.out.print("[" + contador[i] + "]");
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Porque no explicas mejor que es lo que quieres hacer para entenderte mejor, explica de que trata tu tarea

Comment: ¡Hola! Mi objetivo es mostrar el vector, y que cada vez que aparezca un número 3, ese valor sea reemplazado por el caracter "E".

Comment: Es decir tu vas generando numeros aleatorios y si alguno de esos numeros es 3 reemplazarlo por la letra "e"

Comment: ¡Así es! Igual lo de los números aleatorios lo hice, para no completar manualmente la matriz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como te indicaba en un comentario y ratifica @Jorgesys, no hay una función del lenguaje Java que explicitamente te convierta el entero 3 en la cadena de caracteres "E". La forma de obtener esa conversión que has empleado es tan válida como otra cualquiera.

Por añadir algo de valor a esta respuesta, permite que haga algunas ligeras modificaciones en tu código para simplificarlo un poco. Una cosa que tienes que tener en cuenta en el futuro es que el código tiende a enmarañarse con el tiempo, a crecer sin mucho control e ir haciéndose cada vez más ilegible y por tanto inmantenible. Los programadores tenemos que cuidar que el código sea lo más limpio posible para luchar con esa entropía.

¿Qué significa toda esa parrafada? Que debemos evitar en lo posible escribir líneas de código superfluas, por ejemplo.

UNO

```
int espacio;
espacio = 0;
```

Es equivalente a

```
int espacio = 0;
```

DOS

```
int num = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
contador[i] = (num);
```

¿Te has dado cuenta que con la variable `num` no haces nada? La inicializas y directamente la asignas a `contador[i]`. ¿Porque no asignar directamente el valor a `contador[i]`?

```
contador[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
```

Por otro lado existe la clase `Random` en el paquete `java.util` que tiene definido el método nextInt que te devuelve un número entre 0 (inclusive) y el valor que tú le pases (exclusivo, no contenido en los valores posibles que devuelve). De forma que podríamos hacer

```
contador[i] = Random.nextInt(10);
```

Con lo cual nos ahorraríamos la multiplicación y el cast a int.

TRES

¿Te has dado cuenta de que dentro de tu bucle `for` pase lo que pase siempre imprimes y de que **la salida por pantalla depende de una condición**? Cuando el valor de una variable depende de una condición, puedes usar el [operador ternario](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operador_ternario). Sabiendo esto, este trozo de código

```
if (contador[i] == 3) { //Detecta numero 3
     String caracter;
     caracter = "E"; //Cambia el 3 por el caracter E
     //caracter = String.valueOf(contador[i]);
     System.out.print("[" + caracter + "]");
} else {
     System.out.print("[" + contador[i] + "]");
}
```

podría simplificarse y quedar

```
String caracter = (contador[i] == 3) ? "E" : Integer.toString(contador[i]);
System.out.print("[" + caracter + "]");
```

Así siete líneas de código se convierten en dos. Puede parecer una tontería pero imagínate cuando tengas un proyecto con miles y miles de líneas de código y tengas que localizar un error. Todas estás pequeñas cosas contribuyen a reducir el número de líneas que tienes que revisar para poder encontrar el error y corregirlo. Ahora que estás empezando es el momento de ir interiorizando estas cosas.

Es cierto que podríamos reducir aún más y quedarnos con

```
System.out.print("[" + ((contador[i] == 3) ? "E" : Integer.toString(contador[i])) + "]");
```

Pero al contrario que `num` en mi primer apunte, aquí `caracter` sí me está aportando algo: legibilidad. Si simplificamos demasiado el código y lo escribimos todo en una sola línea, se vuelve difícil de comprender. Hay que buscar el equilibrio entre la "verborrea" (excesivas líneas) y la "sobresimplificación" (muy pocas líneas pero muy complejas). Eso ya lo irás decidiendo con la experiencia.

Tu código aplicando todas estas sugerencias - más un pequeño cambio en el nombre del paquete para respetar las convenciones de Java que no recomiendan el uso de mayúsculas ahí - quedaría

```
package segundo.paquete;

public class Cambio {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    int[] contador = new int[27];

    for (int i = 0; i < 27; i++) { // Crear vector
        contador[i] = Random.nextInt(10);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 27; i++) { // Mostrar vector
       String caracter = (contador[i] == 3) ? "E" : Integer.toString(contador[i]);
       System.out.print("[" + caracter + "]");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Wow! ¡Super agradecido por tu aporte! Con respecto a unificar en una sola línea para que quede así, "tipo nombre_variable =  valor;" , cada vez que lo pongo así NetBeans me lo resalta en amarillo, y como me parece molesto ver ese subrayado, lo termino subdividiendo, así que buscaré si se puede configurar para que, escribiéndolo así, no me lo subraye.  ¡¡Super interesante y útil tu respuesta!!

Comment: @NachoMartínez Yo uso Eclipse, ahí no puedo ayudarte pero seguramente podrás desactivarlo por lo que he visto de los "code hints" de NetBeans. ¿Qué aviso te da?

Answer (score 1):

Al detectar el valor de 3 simplemente reemplazalo por E, de hecho ya lo estabas logrando.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int espacio;
    espacio = 0;
    int[] contador;
    contador = new int[27];
    for (int i = 0; i < 27; i++) { // Crear vector
        int num = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
        contador[i] = (num);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 27; i++) { // Mostrar vector
        espacio = espacio + 1;
        if (contador[i] == 3) { //Detecta numero 3
            String caracter;
            caracter = "E"; //Cambia el 3 por el caracter E
            //caracter = String.valueOf(contador[i]);
            System.out.print("[" + caracter + "]");
        } else {
            System.out.print("[" + contador[i] + "]");
        }
    }
    
    
}
```

No existe una función para realizar la conversión de 3 a E por lo tanto esto que implementaste inicialmente debe ser la solución.

Comment: ¡Hola! Tu propuesta fue mi solución primera como se puede ver en la línea comentada de mi código, pero mi objetivo es resolver preferentemente la cuestión a través de una conversión.

Comment: @NachoMartínez ¿A qué te refieres con que no es una conversión? String.valueOf(3) convierte el int 3 en la cadena "3". No hay ninguna función java predefinida que dado el int 3 devuelva la cadena "E". Esa "conversión" tienes que implementarla tú como mejor prefieras.

Comment: ¡¡Muchísimas gracias por esa valiosa información, @RubioRic!! ¿Sabés cómo puedo seleccionar tu comentario como respuesta, si es que se puede?

Comment: No hay una función para convertir el 3 en E , por eso esta sería la opcion a realizar, Para seleccionar una respuesta @NachoMartínez lo puedes ver aquí Nacho [tour], seleccionando la flechita hacia arriba si es que te sirvió la respuesta y seleccionando la flecha verde, saludos.

Comment: @NachoMartínez De nada, hombre. He añadido una respuesta como tal, intentando aportar algo más de valor que un simple comentario. Puedes seleccionarla como respuesta como te indica Jorge, si lo consideras oportuno.